# Hive: Insert into hive table with column using select 1

Tags: hadoop, insert, hive

Let's say I have a hive table test_entry with column called entry_id.

```
hive> desc test_entry;
OK
entry_id                int
Time taken: 0.4 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Suppose I need to insert one row into this above table using `select 1` (which returns 1). For example: A syntax which looks like the below:

```
hive> insert into table test_entry select 1;
```

But I get the below error:

```
FAILED: NullPointerException null
```

So effectively, I would like to insert one row for entry)id whose value will be 1 with such a select statement(without referring another table).

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive does not support what you're trying to do. Inserts to ORC based tables was introduced in Hive 0.13.

Prior to that, you have to specify a FROM clause if you're doing `INSERT .. SELECT`

A workaround might be to create an external table with one row and do the following

`INSERT .. SELECT 1 FROM table_with_one_row`

Comment: This is what I was afraid of. I wanted to avoid the creation of an external table. Thank you for your response.